# Install openvpn custom config on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to install OpenVPN on an iPhone 7 but can't get the OpenVPN app t open with the config file. I uploaded my own ovpn file to Google Drive and when I click on it it I can select "Open In" which shows me some apps including OpenVPN. If I tap OpenVPN it just flies away instead of opening the app.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) question. Please see the meta post linked above for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the hold reviewed.

Comment: I found gmail to work fine but iCloud Drive not to work on my iPhone 4S with iOS 9.3.5. There is an openVPN bug 14 months old on this topic and there has been no activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the native Mail app which did work while Gmail and Drive would not work.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have been able to install OpenVPN files is through iTunes (MacOS High Sierra and iOS 11)

- Select the device icon in iTunes
- A new menu of options on left will appear, select *File Sharing*
- Scroll to find the OpenVPN app, click it - this reveals a file drop area
- Drag a folder containing the config files to the file drop area in iTunes
- Access the OpenVPN app and you should see a new screen asking to import (green ball with a '+' symbol) the VPN config config.
  [image]

I tried the following methods without success:

- Google Drive
- Dropbox
- Files (iOS)
- Gmail
- Mail (iOS)